# Where to place Objective-C dealloc?

Tags: objective-c

I have two questions about dealloc in Obj-C.

1)  Are you supposed to declare -(void)dealloc; in the header file, or is it optional to place it in the header?

2) If you have a parent class that acts as more of an interface, should you also put an empty dealloc method there, or just use it on the child class that makes use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to declare `dealloc` in the header file. You are overriding `dealloc` which is already declared from `NSObject`.

Just add the implementation of `dealloc` in the .m file for the class that actually needs to do something in a `dealloc` method.

It won't hurt anything to add an empty `dealloc` (assuming you are using ARC) in a class but there's also no point.